# SCSS: -ms-prefix causes error in CSS file

Tags: css, sass, css-grid, live-sass-compiler

I am using the **Live Sass Compiler** in Visual Studio Code.

My SCSS file contains this grid:

```
$grid-cols: 12;
$grid-gutter-x: 16px;
$grid-gutter-y: 16px;

.grid {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat($grid-cols, minmax(0, 1fr)) !important; 
    grid-gap: $grid-gutter-x $grid-gutter-y;
}
```

The compiled CSS code:

```
.grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(0, 1fr))[12] !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr)) !important;
  grid-gap: 16px 16px;
}
```

As a result, I get four errors:

```
] expected
semi-colon expected
{ expected
{ expected
```

This line causes the errors:

```
 -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(0, 1fr))[12] !important;
```

My Question is: Is it possible to ignore the following line? Can I prevent my compiler
to add the  `-ms` prefix? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

```
 grid-template-columns: repeat($grid-cols, minmax(0, 1fr)) !important;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Live Sass Complier [documentation](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md)

And you will see this:

> `liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix` : Automatically add vendor
>   prefixes to unsupported CSS properties (e. g. `transform` ->
>   `-ms-transform`).
>
> Specify what browsers to target with an array of strings (uses [Browserslist](https://github.com/ai/browserslist)).
>
> Set null to turn off. (Default is `null`)
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
>    "> 1%",
>    "last 2 versions"    
> ]
> ```

So if this is `null` by default check if you already set this in your settings, if so change accordingly to fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version(4.3.0) of Live Sass Compiler extension on vscode, it fixed the same issue for me.